# How to highlight a particular marker on a multiple marker map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have situation here, kindly help me  in resolving this
On a  map with multiple markers i am using two variables for longitude and latitude and using them as center point of the map.

How can I

1. use the marker for these lat/long used for  center to bounce or
   animate
2. change the icon of this centered marker to be different than others
3. add additional info in the info box.

thanks in advance for the help

-----here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

var lat1 = '-33.92'
var long1 = '151.25'

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, long1),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));


    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var lat_center = -33.923036,
        long_center = 151.259052;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat_center, long_center),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i, text;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
      });

      text = locations[i][0];

      if(locations[i][1] === lat_center && locations[i][2] === long_center) {

          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
               marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/purple.png');
        text += '<br>' + 'Additionl text for centered marker';
      }

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, text) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(text);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, text));
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[List of markers available by google](http://mabp.kiev.ua/2010/01/12/google-map-markers/)

[More about markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers)

Comment: Many thanks alkis
it works perfect with just one small glitch
please consider this 

block of location in the code is static and will always have 5 entries including Coogee Beach
as a result there will six marker now with duplicate marker on coogee beach 
how can we remove/update the coogee beach marker so that only and have only 5 markers on map and the updated one is with new

Comment: I've updated the code. If this answers your question don't forget to mark it as answered and maybe upvote :P .

Comment: alkis , you are a star ... it worked like a charm ...i wish if i could do upvote to the answer but don't have enough reputation count

Comment: @alkis Is there any reason to use an array of arrays instead of an array of JS objects?

Comment: Nope. None at all. It's just a demo to get the OP moving. Nothing more and since the original work of the OP was with an array of arrays I decided not to change it, since it would cause confusion.